# How to fix a non-null String must be provided to a Text widget

Tags: flutter

this is part of my code, I keep getting a non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
Still new to flutter, so I'm not sure on how to fix this. I tried putting the ??"" on child: Text(myQuiz[0][i.toString()] but then it gave me an error on The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling:

```
  Widget optionButton(String k) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 10
      ),
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () => checkAns(k),
        child: Text(
          myQuiz[1][i.toString()][k],
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontFamily: "Open Sans",
            fontSize: 16.0,
          ),
          maxLines: 1,
        ),
        color: buttonColor[k],
        minWidth: 200.0,
        height: 45.0,
        shape:
        RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
            side: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffb0dab9))),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.portraitDown, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              content: Text("You must finish this quiz :)"),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Ok',
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ));
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Quiz'),backgroundColor: Color(0xffb0dab9)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[100],
        body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
               Container(
                 padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(myQuiz[0][i.toString()],
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
             AbsorbPointer(
                absorbing: disableAnswer,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      optionButton('a'),
                      optionButton('b'),
                      optionButton('c'),
                      optionButton('d'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  showTimer ,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helping, I have found the answer, it was in the getRandom, as the json does not have a 0, so when the quiz runs and hit 0, it causes the error

Answer (score 0):

It is because a `null value` is being provide to your `Text` widget

From your code.. one or more of the following is **null** and **not a string**

```
myQuiz[1][i.toString()][k]
showTimer
```

Try

```
...
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print(myQuiz[1][i.toString()][k]);
  print(showTimer);
```

to find out which is the **null value**

Comment: I think (myQuiz[1][i.toString()][k]); is problem, how do i fix it
this is the error that I get now
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("a")

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Text(
          myQuiz[1]?[i?.toString()]?[k] ?? "Default Value",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontFamily: "Open Sans",
            fontSize: 16.0,
          ),
          maxLines: 1,
        ),
```

Comment: i cant put the ? after the [1] and the ? after the tostring as well